# use subset of firebase admin features

Tags: go, firebase-admin

is it possible to use only subset of [firebase-admin-go](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go) on the backend? it ships with a ton of [features](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) but all i need are:

1. `ID Token Verification`
2. `Firebase Cloud Messaging`

so i was hoping i could do something like:

```
import (
   fb "firebase.google.com/go/newapp" // doesn't exist on its own but needed to initiate app
   auth "firebase.google.com/go/auth"
   messaging "firebase.google.com/go/messaging"
   ...
)
```